# I want to create a JAVA window with 3 textfields and 2 buttons

Tags: java

I want to create a simple Java window with 3 text fields and 2 buttons. I want the buttons to perform subtraction and division operations taking input from the user. I need help in the actionPerformed method with the if-else conditions. I can't figure out what condition to write in the if-else parentheses.

I wrote the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class Event extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
 TextField tf, tf1, tf2;
 Event()
 {
  tf=new TextField();
  tf.setBounds(60,50,170,20);
  tf1=new TextField();
  tf1.setBounds(60,70,170,20);
  tf2=new TextField();
  tf2.setBounds(60,90,170,20);
  Button b=new Button("Subtraction");
  b.setBounds(100,120,80,30);
  b.addActionListener(this);
  Button b1=new Button("Division");
  b1.setBounds(100,160,80,30);
  b1.addActionListener(this);
  add(b);
  add(b1);
  add(tf);
  add(tf1);
  add(tf2);
  setSize(300,300);
  setLayout(null);
  setVisible(true);
 }
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {
  if(ActionListener(Subtraction))
  {
   int a,b,c;
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
   a=sc.nextInt();
   tf.setText("Enter first value: "+a);
   b=sc.nextInt();
   tf1.setText("Enter second value: "+b);
   c=b-a;
   tf2.setText("Result is: "+ c);
  }
  else
  {
   int d,f,g;
   Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
   d=sc.nextInt();
   tf.setText("Enter first value: "+d);
   f=sc.nextInt();
   tf1.setText("Enter second value: "+f);
   g=d/f;
   tf2.setText("Result is: "+g);
  }
 }
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  new Event();
 }
}
```

Comment: Newbie hint: use more than one character for your variable names. a, b, c, ... and then tf, tf1, and hey, *another* b that is button, and not an int. Do never write such code, even for a quick example. Always write code as if your life would depend on other people being able to read and understand it quickly. Use names that mean what they say, and say what they mean.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using two different action listeners:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Event extends Frame {
 TextField tf, tf1, tf2;
 Event()
 {
  tf=new TextField();
  tf.setBounds(60,50,170,20);
  tf1=new TextField();
  tf1.setBounds(60,70,170,20);
  tf2=new TextField();
  tf2.setBounds(60,90,170,20);
  Button b=new Button("Subtraction");
  b.setBounds(100,120,80,30);
  b.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
  { 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
  int num1 = Integer.parseInt(tf.getText());
  int num2 = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());

   tf2.setText(Integer.toString(num1 - num2));
  }
   });
  Button b1=new Button("Division");
  b1.setBounds(100,160,80,30);
  b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
  {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
  int num1 = Integer.parseInt(tf.getText());
  int num2 = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());

   tf2.setText(Integer.toString(num1 / num2));
  }
   });

  add(b);
  add(b1);
  add(tf);
  add(tf1);
  add(tf2);
  setSize(300,300);
  setLayout(null);
  setVisible(true);
 }

 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  new Event();
 }
}
```

When you click on subtract it subtracts the numbers in text box 1 and text box 2 and displays the result in text box 3.

When click on divide it divides the numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking on `ActionEvent` which is being passed into your `actionPerformed` method. The `ActionEvent` contains information about the source of the action. A possible way to use this would be with an 'action command':

```
final String subtractionCommand = "Subtraction";

...

Button b=new Button("Subtraction");
b.setActionCommand(subtractionCommand);
b.setBounds(100,120,80,30);
b.addActionListener(this);

...

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  if(e.getActionCommand().equals(subtractionCommand))
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Or by using the `getSource()` method, this is a bit uglier, but as you'll see it returns you the actual object on which the listener is invoked:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  if(((JButton) e.getSource()).getText().equals("Subtraction")) {
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

As a final suggestion I would say to drop the implementation of ActionListener on your main class and create 2 different listeners for both buttons.This way you can separate the code for each action which is a bit cleaner certainly if you would plan to add additional buttons, or invoke the same action from within other places in your application.